# Can't use object variables without getter methods

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have an `abstract` class, `AbstractNode`, and a concrete class which extends it- Node.

I am trying to "program to an interface" by declaring objects of `AbstractClass` and instantiating them with new Node().

When I try to use the variables in Node after initializing them in the constructor, I get a Null Pointer. But everything works fine if I use a getter method instead. What am I missing?

```
public abstract class AbstractNode
{    
    String str;
    public abstract String getStr();
}

public class Node extends AbstractNode
{
    String str;

    public Node()
    {
        str= new String();
    }

    public String getStr()
    {
        return str;
    }
}
```

And the main method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    AbstractNode n= new Node();
    String nullStr= n.str;
    String regularStr= n.getStr();
}
```

Now, `nullStr` contains a `null` reference, and `regularStr` contains a reference to `n.str`.
What is happening in here?
I can access other primitive type fields which do not require initialization, like int, directly without any getter methods.

Answer (score 7):

You're "shadowing" the variable `str`. `AbstractNode` has a `String` named `str`, and then `Node` has a different `String`, also named `str`. The constructor for `Node` assigns an empty string to `Node.str`, but `AbstractNode.str` is still `null` because it's never been assigned. `getStr()` returns the value in `Node.str` because that's the "nearest" variable named `str` it sees. Your code in `main` is reading `AbstractNode.str` because the compiler is resolving its full name at compile time, and the declared type of the variable `n` is `AbstractNode`. Remove the duplicate `String str` in `Node`.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, nullStr contains a Null reference, and regularStr contains a reference to n.str. What is happening in here?

You've got *two* `str` variables - one declared in `AbstractNode`, and one declared in `Node`.

Now `n` is declared to be `AbstractNode`, so this:

```
String nullStr = n.str;
```

fetches the value of the variable declared in `AbstractNode`, whereas this:

```
String regularStr= n.getStr();
```

calls the method declared in `Node`, which returns the variable declared in `Node`.

Lessons you should learn:

- Decide how many pieces of state an object should have, and only declare that many variables. Any time you have two variables with the same name in a class hierarchy, you should *at least* feel uncomfortable. If they genuinely represent different pieces of state, you should be able to find different names.
- If you only have private fields, shadowing becomes mostly irrelevant, as you won't *have* direct access to the fields anyway.

I would suggest a fix of *only* declaring `str` in `AbstractNode`, ideally making it final, and making a `protected` constructor which accepts a value for it. You *probably* want to have an accessor to that in `AbstractNode` as well, although it's unclear. `str` isn't a descriptive name for the variable either - is it the value of the node? The name of the node? Who knows. My classes would be something like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode {
    private final String name;

    protected AbstractNode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    // Presumably some abstract methods?
}

public final class Node extends AbstractNode {
    public Node() {
        super("Some default name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while *methods* are overridable, *fields* are not.

Because you declared the type of the variable as `AbstractNode`, the expression `n.str` references the field in `AbstractNode`, even though the actual type is `Node`. This is because fields are statically bound at compile time to the type.

Methods on the other hand are resolved at runtime, that's why you can override them: the expression `n.getStr()` is resolved based on the actual type of the object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getStr()
{
    return str;
}
```

and

```
String regularStr= n.getStr();
```

This function is overriden and at runtime the corresponding function in Node class is selected and hence you get appropriate results.

But when you say

```
String nullStr= n.str;
```

n variable from AbstractNode class is fetched(which is null).Note that Variables are read only and cannot be overriden,